# How to get a path of the file name in node js

Tags: node.js, electron

I'm working on desktop application using electronjs .I have name of the exe of application such as calculator,spotify,..etc . I want to launch those application from my electron application. In order to launch it I need path of those application exe. Is there any node js npm to ahcieve this or any electron library methods.

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid if there is a package who does that. ( you can still google and see if you find anything).
How I would have approached this, I would save the executable path in environment variable and then run the program (you can google how to do that. typically you just spawn a process and pass arguments to it) based on the passed name.

thanks

Comment: I have done it through this one :- execSync('where /r C:\\ '+ exeArray[0]+'.exe') . problem is, it takes lot of time to search it .If there is lot of exe name in the array and each time it should search for that exe .so it takes a lot of time

Comment: @Krazy I'm not sure they meant the PATH environment variable but, that your user shall configure the executable path into an environment variable of your choice. Did I understand your answer correctly George ?